# I want to learn everything and it is doing more harm than good

Tags: productivity

I got really bad problem. First of all, I am studying for exams, and we have syllabus for exams. And 80% of questions in this exam are repeated from the past year question papers of last 10 years. I have this weird fantasy that whenever I understand a subject well, I want to dive even deeper to the point I am doing worthless and useless stuffs that won't be asked in exams and wasting my time on them. How do I prevent this idiotic behaviour. It is really not good for getting good grades in exam. Also it makes me feel less confident as I encounter stuffs that I can't learn that easily.

Comment: "Help, I find the material interesting and want to learn more than is taught in class"

Comment: Can you please clarify: are you getting poor grades, or just not perfect grades?

Comment: @jakebeal I am not sure about that. Because my exam results are not yet out. My learning has changed a lot in short time. Before that although my overall grades were poor, there used to be some subjects which I was interested in and I used to do like that and get ~70% grades in them. I am wasting time on useless things that is concerning. My goal should be exams and nth else at the moment.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- there is a huge issue with this indeed I will tell you. First of all I get interested in this and that which are never asked in exam. Secondly I just have very very few days for the upcoming exam. Thirdly I should instead put that time into sth else rather than trying to learn this and that, this is not the time to learn this and that rather to focus on exams only.

Comment: @watcus I'm afraid that I'm rather confused about what question you're actually trying to get answered.  Are you trying to ask whether others agree that you're studying "wrong" or are you trying to ask about self-management techniques, or something else entirely?

Comment: Take fewer classes.

Comment: Why must you focus on exams only?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- because time is limited and I should get good grades so that I can get better opportunities for my masters. as simple as that.

Comment: You might want to pay attention to the language you are using in this question: "really bad", "weird", "worthless", "useless" and "idiotic". It could be that you are judging yourself too harshly. Consider using less loaded words.

Answer (score 2):

For the short-term goal of passing exams (and earning credits), you are right to focus somewhat and not become lost diving down too many interesting rabbit holes. However, wanting to learn more is a sign of an eager and curious mind, a thirst for knowledge and a desire to go beyond what may be merely a superficial understanding. That is admirable and entirely healthy if kept in balance. Deeper knowledge can stand you in good stead in your future studies/career and is certainly not worthless! You are already aware of the dangers of getting the balance wrong. Set yourself a time limit - no more than a certain number of hours a day (or week) going beyond the exam material. As for confidence, accept that there is much out there on the frontiers that very few understand well. It is good to get used to that feeling, as you will encounter it again, especially if you become a researcher.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: please do not be so hard on yourself. What you call "idiotic behaviour" is behavior that most teachers want their students to engage in.

I don't think you should stop wanting to learn more about topics that may have no relevance for the exam. Instead, I think you should first learn the core material that **will** be on the exam, and then focus on the more interesting material later. This will require good time management skills, but if you can do this, you will satisfy your need to delve deeper into a subject area and get good grades. Of course, you need to have a familiarity with the core material that will be tested in the exam, but please do not think of your interest in "worthless" topics as meaningless. It can be very beneficial, as it could allow you to have more of an understanding about a subject than your classmates who will only study what is required.

In my experience, it is often the case that in exams, the content on the exam will always be a bit more challenging than the content you will study in class. By taking an interest in the subject and finding out more about it than you need to, you may be at an advantage when it comes to answering some of the more difficult questions in the exam.

Please do not stop being curious.